# Trying to label areas within a 2d space in python(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe made up of several rows of x and y coordinates. I'm trying to label certain 'boxes' within the space as startboxes where the object that was tracked was in before moving into the main space. Coordinates in these boxes extend beyond the main area which is a square from -25 to 750 on both x- and y-axis.

Here is my intial approach:

```
def position(row,df):
if df[df['y'] > 750] and df[200 > df['x'] > 500]:
    df['position'] = NBOX
if df[df['x'] > 750] and df[200 > df['x'] > 500]:
    df['position'] = WBOX
if df[df['y'] < -25] and df[200 > df['x'] > 500]:
    df['position'] = SBOX
if df[df['x'] < -25] and df[200 > df['y'] > 500]:
    df['position'] = EBOX
else:
    df['position'] = arena

for row in df.index:
df.loc[row, 'position']=position(row,df)
```

I get this error if i try to run it:
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I was wondering if anyone had any advice on how to fix it or suggestions on another approach. Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Edit 1:
sample data:

```
python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [31,0,570,449,-15,344,251,136,-2,707]},{'y': [673,393,101,244,388,-153,344,547,576,211]}, {'position': [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a]})
print (df)
      x       y   position
0     31   673       a #a is just a placeholder
1     0    393       a
2     570  101       a
3     449  244       a
4     -15  388       a
5     344  -153      a
6     251  344       a
7     136  547       a
8     -2   576       a
9     707  211       a
```

For example I'd like row 5 to be the south box (SBOX) in the column position and row 0 to be arena.

Edit 2:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TwKY.png
Sample data to help visualise, in which both Westbox and Southbox (WBOX & SBOX) have points

Comment: Read about two functions: numpy select and pandas between. They can be both helpful here to write it without creating a new function.

Comment: Thank you. So for example if I used between, for say NBOX, if both the x and y values were true, then in 'position' I could set it as NBOX?

Comment: No, between could be used to declare a range for df['x'] or df['y'], for example df['x'].between(200,500) instead of 200 > df['x'] > 500, but it's only for the visual aspect. You issue is different here. Such error appear when you try to compare one value to the whole series. It would be easier if you put any sample data in your post and also expected output. I think that multiple "if" is not necessary here.

Comment: I've added some sample data if that help make what I'm aiming for clearer

Comment: Ok and last question, what are NBOX, WBOX etc.? Are they string variables or would you like to put strings in column "position": "NBOX", "SBOX" and so on?

Comment: They're startboxes for the arena. They'd go into the position column as strings I think yes. The goal later would be to filter out certain ones in another piece of code I've made.

Comment: I checked it with np.select and it works, but conditions still seem to be awkward. At first - we have condition that df['x'] should be lesser than 200 and greater than 500 what is impossible, but I assume it should be df['x'] between 200 and 500. If so, for your cases we have 'arena' for positions 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9; 'SBOX' for positions 3, 6; 'EBOX' for position 5. 'NBOX' and 'WBOX' don't appear in above cases. Is it something what you expect? If so, I'll add my answer, if not - paste a table with expected output where you have values in column position filled with data you expect.

Comment: For the first problem yes that was a mistake on my part its should be < < rather than > > throughout. Second I added what a plot of all the locations would look like to help visualise. I'm trying to get 5 positions, say arena '0' would be the central area occupied by points within -25 and 750 on both x and y. The boxes would be in the parts that protrude in the graph, as an entrace/exit.

Comment: For np.select you can declare a list of conditions and then list of choices. For example: conditions = [((df['y'] > 750) & (df['x'].between(200,500)), ((df['x'] > 750) & (df['x'].between(200,500)), ...] and two more. Then we have a list of choices, what means - what should be returned when condition is met: choices = [NBOX, WBOX, ... ]. Then we do: np.select(conditons, choices, default='arena') and it should get you the expected output. You can create a plot after that.

Comment: Thanks that sounds a lot better than what I eventually got to work which was a variation on the function that feels quite messy

Comment: We don't often use functions with multiple "if" or "for loops" when we work with dataframes. Sometimes it's impossible to avoid it, but it's always worth to consider other methods at the beginning :)